# How to prove this induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have these things defined below:

Let $x_{n,k}$ be defined for all the $x,k \geq 0$.

$$x_{0,k} = \begin{cases}1 \textrm{ if } k = 0, 
\\0  \textrm{ if }  k > 0.\end{cases}
$$

and $x_{n+1,k} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} x_{n,i}$ for $n \geq 0$  and $k \geq 0$

Show that $x_{1,k} = 1$,  $x_{2,k} = k + 1$ $x_{3,k} = (k+1)\cdot(k+2)/2$

I think this is the formula to use $ S(k) = \frac{k\cdot (k+1)}{2} $

If you $k=1$ then $\frac{1\cdot(1+1)}{2} = 1$

And $k+1$  =   $\frac{k+1\cdot(k+1)}{2} + (k+2)$

Becomes $\frac{k+1\cdot (k+2)}{2}$

But i am not sure how to prove the induction for

$x_{n,k} = \frac{(k+1)\cdot(k+2)\cdot\cdot\cdot(k+n-1)}{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdot \cdot \cdot (n-1)}$

Or don't know how to begin?

Comment: What do you mean by "I think this is the formula to use $S(k) = \frac{k\cdot(k + 1)}2$"?  Setting aside what $S(k)$ is, you are *given* the equations you are supposed to try to prove; no guesswork is involved there.

Comment: Also posted to (but soon to be deleted from) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435366/how-to-prove-this-induction

Comment: Try induction with respect to $k$.

Comment: @Jochen Shoul i put in k+n-1 in S(K) ?

Comment: In addition to my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585144/how-to-prove-this-induction#comment9654524_4585144)—you still [seem to be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4585144/how-to-prove-this-induction#comment9655040_4585144) using a function $S(k)$ that has never been defined—what does $k + 1 = \frac{k + 1\cdot(k + 1)}2 + (k + 2)$ mean?  The equality is not true.  And what does "becomes $\frac{k + 1\cdot(k + 2)}2$" mean?  All else aside, it seems likely that you meant $\frac{(k + 1)(k + 2)}2$, but still you have not explained what is becoming that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The following might be helpful to find an approach for an induction proof. Here we have *binomial coefficients* in disguise. Starting with the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
x_{0,k}&=\begin{cases}
1&\qquad\qquad k=0\\
0&\qquad\qquad k>0
\end{cases}\\
x_{n,k}&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}x_{n-1,j}\qquad n\geq 1, k\geq 0\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we look at a table for small values
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrr}
n/k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\hline
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&1&\color{blue}{1}&1&1&1\\
2&1&2&3&\color{blue}{4}&5&6&7&8\\
3&1&3&\color{blue}{6}&10&15&21&28&36\\
4&1&\color{blue}{4}&10&20&35&56&84&120\\
5&\color{blue}{1}&5&15&35&70&126&210&340\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
We see the table above contains *Pascal's triangle* in rotated form.

> We obtain from (1) for $n,k\geq 1$ and the table
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{x_{n,k}}&=\sum_{j=0}^kx_{n-1,j}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x_{n-1,j}+x_{n-1,k}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=x_{n,k-1}+x_{n-1,k}}\\
> x_{n,k}&=\binom{n+k-1}{k}\\
> \color{blue}{\binom{n+k-1}{k}}&\color{blue}{=\binom{n+k-2}{k-2}+\binom{n+k-2}{k-1}}
> \end{align*}